# calculate date difference from JSON date strings

Tags: javascript, json

I have dates stored in `timesheet.json` in this format:

```
[{"id":1,"note":"some note about task 1","start":"2015-08-28 02:41:02
    +0200","end":"2015-08-28 02:58:58 +0200","sheet":"job"},{"id":2,"note":"some
    note about task 2","start":"2015-09-03 03:15:04 +0200","end":"2015-09-03
    03:57:34 +0200","sheet":"job"},{"id":3,"note":"some note about task
    3","start":"2015-09-03 23:09:50 +0200","end":"2015-09-03 23:58:00
    +0200","sheet":"job"},{"id":5,"note":"this is a test task","start":"2015-09-08
    19:46:19 +0200","end":"2015-09-08 20:11:22 +0200","sheet":"job"}]
```

As I natively don't have a difference exported in json I am trying to
calculate it myself, and append it to originally parsed json, before sending it to
`handlebars.js` for template rendering.

However I cannot convert the above string representations into `Date()`
objects, to be able to do calculations on time difference.

This construction works in `node` cli, and I can do `startTime.getTime()` but
it doesn't work in javascript:

```
    var startTime = new Date('2015-08-28 02:58:58 +0200');
```

Here is the code which doesn't work:

```
    $.getJSON('./timesheet.json', function(data){

        context.tasks = data;

        for (var prop in context.tasks){

            var startTime = new Date(context.tasks[prop].start);

            console.log(startTime); // Invalid Date
            console.log(context.tasks[prop].start); // 2015-08-28 02:41:02 +0200

            var endTime = new Date(context.tasks[prop].end);

            var diff = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime(); // this doesn't work as endTime and startTime are not Date objects!
            cosole.log(diff); // yields NaN
        }
        var html = template(context);

        $('.tasklist').append(html);
    });
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using a `for in` loop.

Comment: Your data is not JSON, and its quite unclear what values you pass to the `Date` constructor, but I'd start debugging right there

Comment: it is JSON, I just didn't put entire JSON file content here, instead I presented format of start and end times, as question is about how to do a calculation with them

Comment: @Amit you can see now  a full JSON file content, as I edited my question to include it.

Comment: If the 2 objects that you say are not Date objects in fact weren't you'd get an exception in that line and not a NaN printed to console on the following line. Debug your code, you're not getting the values you think you do.

Comment: See another edit, the two added `console.log()` statements after `var startTime = ...`.

Comment: Where *exactly* does this work, and where does it not? I was able to replicate it working on node (Ubuntu), and not working on IE (Windows). Is that your case?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for this.  Then your code becomes the following.  I added some examples of using the moment.js duration api which is usually a better way to look at a date difference.

```js
$.getJSON('./timesheet.json', function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var startTime = moment(data[i].start);
        var endTime = moment(data[i].end);

        var diff = endTime.diff(startTime); // Difference in milliseconds
        console.log(diff);

        var duration = moment.duration(diff); // Duration object which may be more useful to you
        console.log('as days: ' + duration.asDays());
        console.log('as minutes: ' + duration.asMinutes());
        // Etc...
    }
});
```

Comment: still gives `NaN` even like this.

Comment: As others have mentioned, there was an issue with the way you were iterating through the array.  Fixed moment.js example's loop.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your json is formatted. But, I think you are accessing your json incorrectly. I tried the following code which yielded the right results.

Make sure you use `for` loop instead of `for..in`

```
var timesheetJson = [{
    'start': '2015-08-28 02:41:02 +0200',
    'end': '2015-08-28 02:58:58 +0200'
}, {
    'start': '2015-09-03 03:15:04 +0200',
    'end': '2015-09-03 03:57:34 +0200'
}];

for (var i=0; i<timesheetJson.length; i++) {

    var startTime = new Date(timesheetJson[i].start);
    var endTime = new Date(timesheetJson[i].end);

    var diff = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
    console.log(diff); 
}
```

Comment: please see my  edit, now you can see the actual JSON file content

Comment: It should work with your json as well. Check this working fiddle with your data.. https://jsfiddle.net/ez1twxha/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your data coming in from the JSON file. There isn't any issue with the actual date manipulation code.

When you get it working, this will convert your result in milliseconds to floating point days:

`diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24`

You can use each step of the formula with a mod `%` expression to return in a more human readable format:

`var seconds = diff / 1000 % 60`

`var minutes = diff / 1000 / 60 % 60`

`var hours   = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 % 24`

`...`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting timestamp in UTC format from database and javascript does not "understand" it how to handle it.
We must rebuilt it by splitting it to parts and get year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, timezone parameters and create date object from it.

So here is solution:

```js
function UTCToDateObject(utcString) {
    var t = utcString.split(/[- :]/);
    var year = t[0];
    var month = t[1]-1;
    var day = t[2];
    var hours = t[3] || 0;
    var minutes = t[4] || 0;
    var seconds = t[5] || 0;

    if(t[6]) { // if timezone parameter exist, we cut hours and minutes to get to +0000
        var hours =+ (-1)*parseInt(t[6].substr(0,3));
        var minutes =+ (-1)*parseInt(t[6].substr(3));
    }

    var utcTime = Date.UTC(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds); // generating UTC time from parameters
    return new Date(utcTime); // return date object
}

function UTCToTime(utc_string) {
    return UTCToDateObject(utc_string).getTime()/1000;
}

function dateDiffUTC(startTime, endTime) {
    return UTCToTime(endTime) - UTCToTime(startTime);
}


$.getJSON('./timesheet.json', function(data){
    context.tasks = data;
    for (var prop in context.tasks){
        var startTime = context.tasks[prop].start;
        var endTime = context.tasks[prop].end;
        var diff = dateDiffUTC(startTime, endTime);
        context.tasks[prop].timeDiff = diff;
        console.log(diff);
    }
    var html = template(context);

    $('.tasklist').append(html);
});
```